# What is returning "nothing" from Excel.Range.find in c#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

What does nothing mean for me, when the API tells me the function returns nothing? Do I need to use a `try-catch` block to call this function? Will it give me an issue if I try to set something equal to nothing? Basically...what is the proper way of handling "nothing"?

```
Excel.Range headers = exSheet.Range[exSheet.Cells[1], exSheet.Cells[numCols]];
Excel.Range columnHeader;

//some code...

columnHeader = headers.Find(columnList[i]);
```

**Documentation-**

> This method returns **Nothing** if no match is found.

[Excel.Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find.aspx#Anchor_1)

Upon reading the documentation I see that this method returns `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` which is fine, but I know I ran into problems earlier with another function that returned a `Range` ([Range.SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells.aspx)) where I had to use a `try-catch` block in order to ensure that I wouldn't crash the program if no special cells were found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [What's the equivalent of Nothing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88470.aspx):

> For reference types, the equivalent of VB's Nothing is C#'s null. For
>   value types, it's the default value - 0, false, etc.

So according to the documentation, you should be fine when simply check for `null`.

Comment: But this isn't visual basics "Nothing", this is C#'s nothing. Will I get an error if I try to set `columnHeader = nothing`?

Comment: The documentation for the Office-API generally uses "Visual Basic"-terminology. And C#'s nothing is null.